# SQL query to check if a key exists and its value is null in JSON column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select rows that has a JSON column where there is an object with a given key and value is `null`.

Example:

```js
{
  "test": null
}
```

I tried the below query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE JSON_VALUE(Column, '$.test') IS NULL
```

Result columns:

- {"test":null}
- {}
- {"prod":1}

This returns the expected rows but also returns rows that doesn't have such key.

How to return only the rows that have the key exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server 2016+:**

You may try to parse the JSON with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The [result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-value) is a table with columns `key` (an `nvarchar(4000)` value that contains the name of the specified property), `value` (an `nvarchar(max)` value that contains the value of the property) and `type`, so you can implement an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table] t
WHERE EXISTS (  
   SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(t.[Column])
   WHERE [key] = N'test' AND [value] IS NULL
)
```

**SQL Server 2022+:**

Another option is a combination of `JSON_PATH_EXISTS()` and `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE 
  JSON_PATH_EXISTS([Column], '$.test') = 1 AND
  JSON_VALUE([Column], '$.test') IS NULL
```

**Note:**

When you use `JSON_VALUE()` and a `strict` path modifier, the result is an error for a wrong path expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Column], 'strict $.test') IS NULL
```

Comment: Aren't there any other options? I find openjson to be quite expensive.

Comment: Yes, `... WHERE JSON_PATH_EXISTS([Column], '$.test') = 1 AND JSON_VALUE([Column], '$.test') IS NULL`, but you need SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `JSON_EXTRACT`

For example:

```
Select *
from table
where JSON_EXTRACT(Column, '$.test') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT` is a MySQL function *not* a SQL Server function.